# What do prefixes like HHH000412 or HCANN000001 mean?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, logging

What are these prefixes `HHH000412` or `HCANN000001` that I'm seeing in my Spring Boot projects? What do they mean?

```
HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.15.Final
HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
```

Are they only used by library developers for reference? Is there any practical use of these prefixes?

Comment: They are message IDs, identifying the message text to display, so that translating the messages to other languages is easy, by not having the message text embedded in the Java code. See e.g. [The Java™ Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/intro/after.html), which shows example of message ID `"greetings"`.

Comment: @Andreas makes sense. What about the format that they use `HHH000412`. Is it some kind of standard format or just something everyone agrees on?

Comment: When you have hundreds or thousands of messages, how do you name them? You just number them incrementally. --- When you have multiple libraries, how do you distinguish them? You prefix them with some initials representing the library in question.